# answer incoming phone call from my application

Tags: android

I want to make my application answer the phone calls so I can have the ability to do some processing before allowing the user to answer maybe just display my activity over the InCallScreen but I can't accomplish this.
when I used intentFilter with `<action android:name="android.intent.action.ANSWER"></action>` when incoming call the InCallScreen start and not my activity and when using broadcastReciever with `<action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"></action>` I can't use abortBroadcast() method because its non-ordered broadcast.
Any help please

EDIT 1
I managed to display my activity over the InCallScreen by wait 1 second before starting my activity in onReceive of broadcastReceiver method but the InCallScreen is displayed first for portion of time which may allow the user to answer before the processing start and if I reduced the time to wait this may cause InCallScreen to be displayed above my activity. Any other solution will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Tedds Droid Tools](https://github.com/teddscofield/teddsdroidtools/wiki). It talks about programmatically answering calls. Specifically, you want to look at the [Features](https://github.com/teddscofield/teddsdroidtools/wiki#features) portion of the Readme.

Comment: Thanks for your help I think the provided link is making reflection and using API's nit included in the SDK which I don't want but I'll review it to be sure

Comment: As I thought it use reflection so I can't use this solution

Comment: I've made some edits to try to make this answer a little more useful.